# Write to (custom) pivot Pandas rows into column in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas data frame with following data

```
Id   Voter   Vote
123   A      Positive
123   B      Negative
123   C      Positive

223   A      Negative   
223   B      Positive 
223   C      Neutral    
223   D      Negative
```

I need a pivoted output like this for above data frame

```
Id   Winner  Confidence
123  Postive  2/3 
223  Negative 2/4
```

I kept Confidence column value as a fraction for easier readability, they can be `2/3 = 0.667` and `2/4 = .5`

The confidence value is calculated based on winning vote give to the winner.
For instance, id=123 has two positive votes out of total 3 votes, so it has confidence 2/3.

If it makes it easy, there will be always a winner.

P.S. I am new to python so any explanation of your solution will be helpful.

Comment: @Julien can you please point me to the tutorial where to find a solution for this. I read through zip and dictionary, but cannot wrap my head around how to answer this.

Comment: @Silveris fixed it, thanks!

Comment: Asking for a tutorial is off topic on SO, and google will answer better than me!

Comment: @Julien if it is so easy for you, wonder if you could kindly write down the quick answer, I will accept it. I really cannot find on google that is why I took the time to write here.

Comment: here is what I read through before writing here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html

Comment: So.. where does confidence column come from?

Comment: @AndrewL I edited the question with more details on confidence value, please let me know if you have further question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you need [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) with parameter `normalize`:

```
df = pd.crosstab(df['Id'], df['Vote'], normalize=0)
print (df)
Vote  Negative  Neutral  Positive
Id                               
123   0.333333     0.00  0.666667
223   0.500000     0.25  0.250000
```

But if need different structure use:

- [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) for count all combination of columns `Id` and `Vote`
- `groupby` + [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for sum by `Id`
- divide by [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html)

---

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Id','Vote']).size()
print (df1)
Id   Vote    
123  Negative    1
     Positive    2
223  Negative    2
     Neutral     1
     Positive    1
dtype: int64

df2 = df1.groupby(level='Id').transform('sum')
print (df2)
Id   Vote    
123  Negative    3
     Positive    3
223  Negative    4
     Neutral     4
     Positive    4
dtype: int64

df3 = df1.div(df2).reset_index(name='col')
print (df3)
    Id      Vote       col
0  123  Negative  0.333333
1  123  Positive  0.666667
2  223  Negative  0.500000
3  223   Neutral  0.250000
4  223  Positive  0.250000
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great!

Comment: The only step left in your answer is to get a single row per ```Id``` with the highest value of ```col```, that will get me desired output as per my original question. I will try to figure it out.

Comment: Do you need `df= df.groupby('Id')['col'].max()` ? Or  `df= df.loc[df.groupby('Id')['col'].idxmax()]` ? Sorry, nottested, because only on phone.

Comment: your solution might be more elegant, but I got it working by getting the max score out of three columns into another column ```df["max_confidence"] = df[["Negative","Neutral","Positive"]].max(axis=1)```. Feel free to write your tested solution, that might help someone else. Meanwhile, I am going to accept your answer.

Comment: No, I think your solution is working fine. If need max from all columns, can be simplify by `df["max_confidence"] = df.max(axis=1)`. Thank you for accepting.

Answer (score 1):

First you'll need to add a new column which will have numeric value for Vote - 1.

```
# data_frame => Given Data_Frame of the form-
Id   Voter   Vote
123   A      Positive
123   B      Negative
123   C      Positive

223   A      Negative   
223   B      Positive 
223   C      Neutral    
223   D      Negative

data_frame['Vote_Numeric'] = data_frame['Vote'].map(lambda x: 1)
```

which gives -

```
    Id      Vote Voter  Vote_Numeric
0  123  Positive     A       1
1  123  Negative     B       1
2  123  Positive     C       1
3  223  Negative     A       1
4  223  Positive     B       1
5  223   Neutral     C       1
6  223  Negative     D       1
```

Now, using pivot_table on the data_frame, we'll have a new frame having columns Id, Positive, Negative, Neutral and summing total votes under each column for each Id

```
df_pivot = data_frame.pivot_table('Vote_Numeric', index='Id', columns='Vote', aggfunc=np.sum)
```

which gives-

```
Vote  Negative  Neutral  Positive
Id                               
123        1.0      NaN       2.0
223        2.0      0.0       1.0
```

Now we'll need to add a column which decides winner based on which column holds max numeric value for each id-

```
df_pivot= df_pivot.fillna(0)
df_pivot['winner'] = df_pivot.idxmax(axis=1)
```

which gives-

```
Vote  Negative  Neutral  Positive    winner
Id                                         
123        1.0      0.0       2.0  Positive
223        2.0      1.0       1.0  Negative
```

Now to get confidence value, divide max value among three(Positive, Negative and Neutral) by sum of all three columns to get new column confidence-

```
df_pivot['confidence'] = df_pivot.max(axis=1, numeric_only=True)/df_pivot.sum(axis=1,numeric_only=True)
```

Result -

```
Vote  Negative  Neutral  Positive    winner  confidence
Id                                                     
123        1.0      0.0       2.0  Positive    0.666667
223        2.0      1.0       1.0  Negative    0.500000
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great, will try out and accept the answer

Comment: One minor problem, remember we don't always divide by Positive, we divide by the whatever is highest vote, it could be anything: Positive, Negative or Neutral

Comment: In my example, id=123 has positive as highest vote and id=223 has Negative as the highest vote. This is why your answer for id=223 is not accurate (sorry)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed.